# Umbraco Forms An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: forms, key, umbraco

I are running Umbraco 7.4.5 with Dialogue 1.1 fanoe starter kit and Forms 4.3.3.

I have created a contact form and tested. all works great.

Now created and entire new form gathering entirely different information and put it on its own page. Are calling this for Dialogues when a user is not permitted to access to a topic.

Now I get this error when ever I try to submit either form.

An item with the same key has already been added.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   Umbraco.Core.Cache.HttpRuntimeCacheProvider.GetCacheItem(String cacheKey, Func`1 getCacheItem, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean isSliding, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback removedCallback, CacheDependency dependency) +963
   Umbraco.Core.Cache.HttpRuntimeCacheProvider.GetCacheItem(String cacheKey, Func`1 getCacheItem, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean isSliding, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback removedCallback, String[] dependentFiles) +107
   Umbraco.Core.Cache.DeepCloneRuntimeCacheProvider.GetCacheItem(String cacheKey, Func`1 getCacheItem, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean isSliding, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback removedCallback, String[] dependentFiles) +114
   Umbraco.Forms.Core.Cache.CacheProviderExtensions.GetCacheItem(IRuntimeCacheProvider provider, String cacheKey, Func`1 getCacheItem, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean isSliding, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback removedCallback, String[] dependentFiles) +225
   Umbraco.Forms.Data.StringHelper.ParseMemberPlaceholders(String value, Object memberKey) +1600
   Umbraco.Forms.Data.StringHelper.ParsePlaceHolders(HttpContext context, Record record, String value) +390
   Umbraco.Forms.Data.StringHelper.ParsePlaceHolders(Record record, String value) +61

........

If I delete the secound form in the backoffice (under Forms) the contact form works.

Has anyone got any surgestions where I start.

Comment: This seems to have fixed itself.

Comment: I"m now having exactly same issue, with my own project. Let me try to recreate the form.